Business Central API to Azure SQL Database - ADF will not interact with or filter incoming API data
We are trying to incrementally load Business Central API data to an Azure SQL database in ADF. ADF only seems to allow you to copy the API data to the target source, however nothing happens when you attempt to look up, filter, or isolate any of the incoming API data...in this case I am trying to incrementally copy via watermarktable and existing load dates. It will correct you if the code is wrong, but when it* is* correct it still just loads the entire API table and will not interact / filter it. I can't figure out why this is happening (Microsoft BS). I was able to successfully interact with the watermark table or data from the SQL source, its only BC API incoming data it doesnt like. This is making it impossible to build this ETL.
Copy activity, for each, lookup will not filter BC API incoming dataset

Can you provide your pipeline flow and activity configurations? and exactly what is the error/blockers here? any sample input and expected output?

First I created an extract API dataset to take it from BC and then created an insert API dataset into SQL table in new database.  Then a lookup (for the two dates/watermark table, and then to a copy activity (where it is supposed to filter the data but will not interact) for incremental copy. I have been able to copy everything over to new database but cannot do anything with incremental. I think it wants me to load everything to a storage container/datalake first before incremental copy. That seems to be the typical solution for every comparable...

but then it still leaves the first issue....how are we supposed to copy over everything to the datalake incrementally? Or do we copy it all over for the incremental piece and drop it after? I am not sure what Microsoft expects us to do we are using ALL of their products for this!

I see examples of copying to datalake and or to a csv file in a file storage, but I dont know what is supposed to work here.

There is nothing blocking it, if you write the code correctly it will run, but when you preview the data, nothing is filtered and it just copies everything. makes no sense

the idea is to use lastmodifieddate columns in the API data for incremental copy

You can do the incremental copying to your target table like below.
First copy your API data to a temporary table in SQL using copy activity. Then, use a lookup activity to get your incremental dates. After lookup activity, use copy activity with your temporary SQL table as source and your target table as target.
In the copy activity source query, use below query to filter out the incremental data.
select * from table1 where mydate>'@{activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].date}'


Later, you can update your lookup table with recent timestamp. In this way, on every pipeline run, the new data will be filtered and copied to the target table.
(OR) you can use dataflow with your API as source. Before the dataflow activity, use lookup on your incremental dates table and pass the dates to dataflow using dataflow parameters. In the dataflow, use filter transformation with dataflow parameters and filter out the new data.
Then, give your target SQL table as sink for the dataflow.

